# send inline keyboard like t.me/username but for userid in telegram php

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to send an inline keyboard in which get the user into somebodey's chat whit his `chat_id` . I know that i can set a Url for inline keyboard like: `t.me/username`
but something like that doesn't work with

```
chat_id : t.me/123456
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `https://` prefix at the start of your `InlineKeyboardButton`'s `url`.

So `reply_markup` parameter of the [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method should look like this:

> `"reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "button text...", "url": "https://t.me/<chat_id or name of another user>"}]]}`.

Full example with `curl`:

> `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"chat_id": 123456, "text": "here is your chat with <USERNAME>", "reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "here is your link to another user", "url": "https://t.me/<USERNAME>"}]]}}' https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_ID>:<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage`

This line sends a `Message` to user with `id` = 123456. `Message` contains inline keyboard with one `InlineKeyboardButton`. This button has a link to chat with another user with id `<USERNAME>` and respective page URL `https://t.me/<USERNAME>`.

#### update

Unfortunately, if user you're looking for does not have a username, you cannot make a `t.me` link, so you cannot contact him:

> You can write to people who are in your phone contacts and have Telegram. Another way of contacting people is to type their Telegam username into the search field.
>   ...
>   You can set up a public username on Telegram. It then becomes possible for other users to find you by that username — you will appear in contacts search under ‘global results’. Please note that people who find you will be able to send you messages, even if they don't know your number. If you are not comfortable with this, we advise against setting up a username in Telegram.

So looks like the only solution here is to ensure that every needed contact has a username.

More information can be found [here](https://telegram.org/faq#q-who-can-i-write-to) and [here](https://telegram.org/faq#usernames-and-t-me).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work with chat_id for example mine is 114505405 and when i try to send a url like https://t.me/114505405 telegram sends it but when i click on butten it says that username @114505405 not found